# How to append Psypark FOR loop output into single dataframe (spark.sql)

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, append

I have a pyspark for loop that uses a "customer" variable. I want to append the output of each loop iteration so that the final dataframe has all the rows output by the for loop. The code works except for the append portion. I have also tried using "union" but without success.

```
df = ""
df_output = []
customer=""

for customer in ['customer_abc', 'customer_xyz']:
  df = spark.sql(f"""
  SELECT sale, sum(amt) as total_sales
  FROM {customer}.salestable
  GROUP BY sale
  """).withColumn('Customer',lit(customer))
  df_output.append(df)
  
display(df_output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your approach you can use a reduce :

```
from functools import reduce
unioned_df = reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y) ,df_output)
```

Or instead of initiating `df_output` as a  `list`, you can initiate it as a `spark dataframe`. and then keep unioning as mentioned by @Luiz

Comment: Do I need to change anything to this? As written, there's no output since df_output is empty. If I replace df_output with df, I get an error (TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable). I'm putting your line of code where I previously had the .append line.

Comment: @z3115 dont replace the append. execute this as a seperate line after running your code as it is. `df_output` should be a list of dfs

Comment: Ah I see! That worked perfectly, thank you so much! You've already helped more than enough so not expecting more help, but if you don't mind - why wasn't my original code working / why is the extra step of the reduce necessary?

Comment: @z3115 Glad it worked. because currently you are appending each subset from the for loop in a list (so you are doing a list.append). However you if would have initialized `df_output` as `F.DataFrame()` (*from pyspark.sql import functions as F*) for example, you can then keep unioning instead of append. like `df_output = df_output.union(df)` in the for loop

Comment: that makes sense, thank you again for both the solution and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

use `df = df.union(df_output)` instead of `df_output.append(df)`

Comment: That causes an error - 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jdf'. Am I doing something wrong that is causing df and df_output to be different (e.g. ones a list ones a dataframe) that prevents them from being joined via union?